# Error "You may need to install the Command Line Tools package through XCode" when package titanium modul?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Does anyone know how to package Titanium module for Android?  Every time I try to package the Titanium module, it give me an error.  Here's my log output:

```
Executing build.xml...
/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.4.GA/module/android/build.xml:362: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.4.GA/module/android/build.xml:317: exec returned: 2You may need to install the Command Line Tools package through XCode, in case you haven't done so yet.
```

Here's my computer spec:

- Mac OS X Snow Leopard
- Titanium 2.1.4GA
- XCode 3.0

and this is my build.properties:

```
titanium.platform=D:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\2.1.4.GA\\android
android.platform=C:\\DeveloperFolder\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\\adt-bundle-windows\\sdk\\platforms\\android-8
google.apis=C:\\DeveloperFolder\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\\adt-bundle-windows\\sdk\\add-ons\\addon-google_apis-google-8
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Many thanks.

Comment: Add your .classpath and build.properties to the question, and update it to let people know that you're trying to do this with Windows now.

Comment: @Dawson Toth: i can find the build.properties but i can't fint where the .classpath is.. do u know where i can find the .classpath? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what it says, installing the Command Line Tools package through Xcode?

Also, that version of Xcode (3.0) is not supported by Titanium Mobile 2.1.4GA. You need to upgrade to at least version 4.2, as detailed in the compatibility matrix: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode

Comment: thanks for your answer dawson.. my mac OS doesn't support XCode 4.2 and i changed to windows.. do you have any information or reference how to create titanium module and how to use it from zero? really confused here.. many thanks..

Comment: Read the manual... http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile

Comment: Thanks, after read that i find some error.. when i try to compile my titanium module, it always give me error: "......:42 Cannot find symbol" in bootstrap.. do you know how to solve it?

Comment: That usually means the .classpath or build.properties files aren't pointing at an existing Ti SDK or Android SDK.

Comment: i've chedked it and looks like the SDK path is on the right place.. any other suggestion?? thankss..

Comment: Add your .classpath and build.properties to the original question.