# titanium android module error when packaging

Tags: android, ant, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817629/error-you-may-need-to-install-the-command-line-tools-package-through-xcode-whe)

I typed to the terminal the `ant` command where the module path is and that's the result

```
Buildfile: /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/build.xml

python.set.exec:

python.check:
     [echo] Testing for Python
     [exec] Python 2.7.2

init:

process.annotations:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/build/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Running Kroll binding generator.
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Succesfully loaded existing binding data: /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/build/generated/json/org/appcelerator/titanium/bindings/deezer-android-module.json
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for module DeezerAndroidModule
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for proxy Example
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:23: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private DeezerConnect deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl( APP_ID );
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnect
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:8: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnect;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:9: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerError;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:10: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerRequest;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:11: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DialogError;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:12: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DialogListener;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:13: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.OAuthException;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]  class MyDialogHandler implements DialogListener {
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol: class DialogListener
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]      private DeezerConnect deezerConnect;
    [javac]              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnect
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]      public MyDialogHandler(DeezerConnect deezerConnect){
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnect
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onDeezerError(final DeezerError deezerError) {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerError
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onError(final DialogError dialogError) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DialogError
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onOAuthException(OAuthException oAuthException) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class OAuthException
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Generating JSON: file:/Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/build/generated/json/org/appcelerator/titanium/bindings/deezer-android-module.json
    [javac] warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kroll.checkTiContext]'
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:23: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private DeezerConnect deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl( APP_ID );
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnect
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:8: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnect;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:9: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerError;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:10: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerRequest;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:11: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DialogError;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:12: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.DialogListener;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:13: error: package com.deezer.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.deezer.sdk.OAuthException;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]  class MyDialogHandler implements DialogListener {
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol: class DialogListener
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]      private DeezerConnect deezerConnect;
    [javac]              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnect
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]      public MyDialogHandler(DeezerConnect deezerConnect){
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnect
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onDeezerError(final DeezerError deezerError) {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerError
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onError(final DialogError dialogError) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DialogError
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onOAuthException(OAuthException oAuthException) {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class OAuthException
    [javac]   location: class MyDialogHandler
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private DeezerConnect deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl( APP_ID );
    [javac]                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerConnectImpl
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest( "/user/me" );
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerRequest
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest( "/user/me" );
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerRequest
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         catch (OAuthException e) {
    [javac]                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class OAuthException
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         } catch (DeezerError e) {
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DeezerError
    [javac]   location: class DeezerAndroidModuleModule
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:21: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:26: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:36: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/MyDialogHandler.java:41: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] Note: /Users/casanostra/Desktop/titanium/deezer-android-module/src/com/deezer/android/ExampleProxy.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 24 errors
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/Users/casanostra/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/module/android/build.xml:163: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

when packaging the module for my titanium project, the console output is displaying

```
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details. You may need to install the Command Line Tools package through XCode, in case you haven't done so yet.
```

of course I installed the command line tools package.
it seems it didn't catched the deezer library that I imported via eclipse.

the ndk path is correct.

my build.properties contains the following lines

```
titanium.platform=/Users/casanostra/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/casanostra/Documents/android/platforms/android-8
google.apis=/Users/casanostra/Documents/android/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-8
```

those paths are corrects. I even tried to change to android-10 and google apis 10 with the same result.

and finally there's my .classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="build/.apt_generated"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/casanostra/Documents/android/platforms/android-10/android.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/casanostra/Documents/android/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-10/libs/maps.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/casanostra/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/titanium.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/casanostra/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/kroll-common.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/casanostra/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/kroll-apt.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=".apt_generated">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/casanostra/Downloads/deezer-android-sdk-0.9.3-v00201005/deezer-sdk-0.9.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I tried also to clean the project and delete the build folder before to build the project.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was solved after deleting the unused `imports` and after to copy my external (`deezer`) library to the lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Move your **.jar** library to **./android/lib/** then add the **.jar** from **Project Properties-> Java Build Bath-> Libraries-> Add JARs** from the **./android/lib/** folder will solve the problem.

Thanks.